# finance - using CAPM

Tags: finance

The risk-free rate is 4%, and the expected return on the market portfolio is 12%. Using the Capital Asset Pricing Model:

a. What is the risk premium on the market?

b. what is the required return on an investment with a beta of 1.5?

c. if the expected return on stock X is 11.2%, what is its beta, according to the capital asset pricing model?

Answer (score 1):

The CAPM states that 
$$
E[r-r_f] = \beta E[r_M-r_f],
$$
thus
$$
E[r] = r_f + \beta E[r_M-r_f],
$$
where $r$ is the return of the asset and $r_M$ is the market return, $r_f$ is the risk free rate.
Thus you have to substract the risk free rate from the expectations as $E[r-r_f] =E[r]-r_f $.
The answers are

1. $8\%$ as in the other answer
2. $4\% + 1.5* 8\% = 16\%$
3. $11.2\%-4\% =\beta*8\%$ thus $\beta=0.9$.